# Slash Command in Discord.js v14 not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to run a command named /setup that grants 3 options. It displays the 3 options, however it seems as if the interaction isn't passed down to the execute. I'm pretty sure it's my InteractionCreate, however I'm new to the js scene but have some experience. I could be only handling buttons/modals and not the actual command in my interaction.

setup.js

```
const { PermissionFlagsBits, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const unbanModal = require('../Modals/unbanModal.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('setup')
        .setDescription('Setup the bot for your server')
        .addChannelOption(option => 
            option.setName('logchan')
            .setDescription('Channel to log moderation actions')
            .setRequired(false)
        )
        .addChannelOption(option => 
            option.setName('appchan')
            .setDescription('Channel to log applications')
            .setRequired(false)
        )
        .addChannelOption(option => 
            option.setName('modalchan')
            .setDescription('Channel to send the appeal application')
            .setRequired(false)
        )
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.KickMembers),
    async execute(interaction) {
        console.log('executing setup');
        try {
            const logChan = interaction.options.getChannel('logchan');
            const appChan = interaction.options.getChannel('appchan');
            const modChan = interaction.options.getChannel('modalchan');
        
            if (logChan || appChan || modChan) {
                console.log('executing unbanModal');
                await unbanModal.execute(interaction);
            } else {
                console.log('No channel was provided');
                interaction.reply({content: 'You must specify at least one channel.', ephemeral: true});
            }
        
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            interaction.reply({content: 'An error occurred while trying to get the channels from your request.', ephemeral: true});
        }        
    }
}
```

main.js

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });
const { botToken } = require('./Src/Credentials/Config.json');

client.commands = new Collection();
client.modals = new Collection();
client.buttons = new Collection();

console.log('client.buttons:', client.buttons);
  

const modalsDir = path.join(__dirname, 'Src', 'Modals');
const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Src', 'Events');
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Src', 'MessageCommands');
const buttonsDir = path.join(__dirname, 'Src', 'Buttons');
console.log('buttonsDir:', buttonsDir);


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const buttonFiles = fs.readdirSync(buttonsDir).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
console.log('buttonFiles:', buttonFiles);
const modalFiles = fs.readdirSync(modalsDir).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);

    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        console.log(`[INFO] Loaded command ${command.data.name}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing either the 'data' or 'execute' property.`);
    }
}

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);

    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

for (const file of buttonFiles) {
    try {
        const button = require(path.join(buttonsDir, file));
        console.log(`[INFO] Loaded button: ${button.name}`);
        client.buttons.set(button.name, button);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`[WARNING] Error loading button at ${path.join(buttonsDir, file)}: ${error}`);
    }
}
console.log('[INFO] CLIENT.buttons:', client.buttons);

for (const file of modalFiles) {
    const modal = require(path.join(modalsDir, file));
    client.modals.set(modal.name, modal);
    console.log(`[INFO] Loaded modal: ${modal.name}`);
}

async function startApp() {
    console.log("Starting...");
    try {
        await client.login(botToken);
        console.log(`Successfully logged in ${client.user.tag}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Failed to login | ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

startApp();

module.exports = {
    client
}
```

interactionCreate.js

```
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {
        //if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

        if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
            const modalName = interaction.customId;
            console.log('modalName:', modalName);
            try {
                console.log('client.modals:', client.modals);
                const modalEvent = client.modals.get(modalName);
                if (!modalEvent) return;


            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error getting modal:', error);
                console.log('client.modals:', client.modals);
                console.log('modalName:', modalName);
            }
            const modalEvent = client.modals.get(modalName);
        
            if (!modalEvent) return;
    
            try {
                await modalEvent.execute(interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error executing modal event "${modalName}":`, error);
                interaction.reply({ content: 'An error occurred while executing this command.', ephemeral: true });
            }
        } else if (interaction.isButton()) {
            const buttonName = interaction.customId;
            console.log('buttonName:', buttonName);
            const buttons = client.buttons;
            if (!buttons) {
                console.log('No buttons found');
                return;
            }
            const buttonEvent = buttons.find(btn => btn.name === buttonName);
            if (!buttonEvent) {
                console.log(`Button event ${buttonName} not found`);
                return;
            }

            try {
                await buttonEvent.execute(interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error executing Button event "${buttonEvent}":`, error);
                interaction.reply({ content: 'An error occurred while executing this command.', ephemeral: true });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question. It's exactly what I anticipated, [`isChatInputCommand`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseInteraction?scrollTo=isChatInputCommand) is what I needed.